# Equivalence of integrals in Classical Electrodynamics

Tags: classical-electrodynamics, integration

I have a technical question about a section from Jackson's Classical Electrodynamics 3rd ed.

In chapter 14, Jackson derives an expression for $ \frac{d^2I}{d\omega d\Omega} $, the frequency spectrum of radiation emitted by a relativistically moving charged particle. On page 675, it reads

$$
\frac{d^2I}{d\omega d\Omega} = \frac{e^2}{4\pi^2c}|\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{\vec{n}\times[(\vec{n}-\vec{\beta}) \times \dot{\vec{\beta}}]}{(1 - \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{n} )^2 }e^{i\omega(t - \frac{\vec{n}\cdot{\vec{r}}}{c})}dt|^2,
$$

where $\vec{n}$ is a unit vector in the direction of the observer; $\vec{r}(t)$ is the particle trajectory etc.

He then notes that

$
\frac{\vec{n}\times[(\vec{n} - \vec{\beta}) \times{\dot{\vec{\beta}}]}}{(1 - \vec{\beta}\cdot\vec{n})^2} = \frac{d}{dt}[\frac{\vec{n} \times (\vec{n} \times \vec{\beta})}{1 - \vec{\beta} \cdot \vec{n}}],
$

which I've been able to prove for myself. He then says that integration by parts leads to

$$
\frac{d^2I}{d\omega d\Omega} = \frac{e^2\omega^2}{4\pi^2c}\biggr\lvert\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} \vec{n} \times (\vec{n} \times \vec{\beta}) e^{i\omega(t - \frac{\vec{n}\cdot{\vec{r}}}{c})} dt\biggr\rvert^2.
$$

He then explains why this second form is stil valid even if $\dot{\vec{\beta}}$ is 0 at all times apart from a small interval $[T_1, T_2]$.

> The reader may rightly ask whether [the second form] is correct in all circumstances as it stands. Suppose that the acceleration is different from zero only for $T_1 \leq t \leq T_2$. Why then is the integration in [the second form] over all time? The precise answer is that [the second form] can be shown, by adding and subtracting integrals over the times when the velocity is constant, to follow from [the first form] provided ambiguities at $t = \pm \infty$ are resolved by inserting a convergence factor $e^{-\epsilon|t|}$ in the integrand and taking the limit $\epsilon \to 0$ after evaluating the integral.

Could somebody give me a practical explanation of how this works please? I'm confused because I've written a simple computer program to approximate both integrals using the trapezium by using $[T_1, T_2]$ as my region of integration; $\dot{\beta} = 0$ outside of this region. Integrating the first form like this gives a good, reasonable spectrum however using the second gives a spectrum which shoots off several orders of magnitude above the first.